# Programming a chessboard using Visual Basic Form Application

Tags: vba, chess

I am trying to program a chess game solely through Visual Basic, using a Windows form. I am a beginner in programming and would like some help. 
So far I have tried looking at array representations and assigning piece values. But I am unsure about how I can go about programming  a working chessboard from scratch.

Comment: That is a _very_ ambitious project for a beginner! Maybe you should start with something simple, like tic-tac-toe.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this might be a bit late, I'll try to answer your question as best as I can.

First off, you have to decide which internal board representation you would like to use.

There are 3 main types used in chessprogramming:
- 2-dimensional 8-by-8 integer array, where x represents the column and y the row, the corresponding integer contains a number representing a piecetype => easy to understand and handle
- 1-dimensional 120 integer array, where you call a field using 10y+x as arrayindex to get and set pieces => a little bit harder to handle, but faster to execute
-Bitboards, which are more advanced stuff and you are not gonna need for your first engine

I would recommend you to use the first option, since you can easily understand and debug it.

After you made a decision about the internal handling, you will have to look at the gui. I recommend a pictureBox there, but a panle or such will do too.

In order to show a Board on screen, you make a new override for [Enter your chosen component here].OnPaint(). First, you draw a chessboard, then you iterate through your array and you draw the picture of the current piece to [component].With/8*X and [component].Height/8*Y.

There you have it, your Board will be drawn into your Form whenever it is being repainted.

I can't describe how to write a whole new chessprogramm here, since it would take me for ever. I you want to learn how a chessprogram works in terms of move generation and search, I recommend the [chessprogramming wiki](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/).

Hope this rather long description helped you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the detailed description. Creating the two dimensional array would be a good way to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed a 2 player hotseat game of Chess using Excel VBA, why not try this before moving on to Windows Forms (which would prove to be more complex)? It uses event procedures, modules, classes and userforms. It has a classic 8x8 board which is represented in cells and uses shapes as pieces. You can download it from this site:

http://excelvbachess.wikidot.com

You can view the commented code using the Visual Basic Editor- it is about 6,000 lines of VBA code in total. I used class modules to model the different pieces (Pawn, Rook, Knight, Bishop, Queen, King) and the Queen inherited some of the movements from Bishop and Rook. Modelling Check, Absolute Pinning and Checkmate was part of the challenge, as well as special moves such as Castling, En Passant and Pawn Promotion.

Again this is rather late, but I hope it gives you (or someone else) some ideas on how to get started.